# Визуально выделить элемент на странице CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть необходимость фокуса на определенных элементах UI (цепляю скрин, что бы было понятно о чем речь). Кто-то делал? Есть-ли готовые решения? И куда копать, что бы такое выделение работало независимо от разрешения? (responsive)

[image: screen]

Comment: Опишите ожидаемое поведение элементов подробнее.

Comment: Возможно, вам надо что-то вроде этого https://introjs.com/